# Datatable move rows button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a two datatables and have this function to move rows from one to the other, it works perfectly as is, but I want to trigger the action not by clicking the row but by clicking a button, tried changing it but won't work.

```
...
stockTable.on('click', 'tr' ,function() {     //'#toggle' selector instead 'tr'
    var $row = $(this);                       // $(this).closest('tr'); instead $(this);
    var addRow = stockTable.fnGetData(this);  //$(this).closest('tr'); instead 
    catalogTable.fnAddData(addRow);
    stockTable.fnDeleteRow($row.index());
});
...
<td><button class="toggle">C</button></td>
....
```

Sorry if the question may seem dumb but I'm ne to javascript.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `tr` with `.toggle` and it should work. You were trying with the ID `#` selector, you need a class `.` selector.

```
stockTable.on('click', '.toggle' ,function() {
```

You then have to re-assign this to the closest `tr`:

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
```

Comment: You'll have to modify the function a bit, but that should get it started.

Comment: Actually now it's that way and giving me "TypeError: a.nodeName is undefined"

    stockTable.on('click', '.toggle' ,function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var addRow = stockTable.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr'););
        catalogTable.fnAddData(addRow);
        stockTable.fnDeleteRow($row.index());
    });

Comment: Managed to do it by adding [0] before semicolon:
var addRow = stockTable.fnGetData($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
THANKS!